# Pandas Melt with Multi Index Data Set and Resetting Index - Why is this working?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created this dataset straight from the pandas documentation:

```
In [28]: columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A', 'cat'), ('B', 'dog'),
   ....:                                      ('B', 'cat'), ('A', 'dog')],
   ....:                                     names=['exp', 'animal'])
   ....: 

In [29]: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([('one', 'two'),
                                             ('bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux')
   ....:                                     ],
   ....:                                    names=['first', 'second'])
   ....: 

In [30]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=index, columns=columns)
```

The MultiIndex dataset (for both columns and rows) looks like this:

[image]

I wanted to get to something like this [the image is truncated but you get the point]

[image]

There are probably a zillion ways of reshaping this but I want to get it done using unstack() and melt()

These are the two ways I came up with:

```
    1. pd.melt(df.reset_index(),id_vars=['first','second'])
    2. pd.melt(df.unstack().reset_index(),id_vars=['first'])
```

So here is where I am stuck: **Why does this work?**

`df.reset_index()` gives me this dataframe

[image]

with these columns

[image]

'first' and 'second' don't show up in the names of columns. They're are infact levels of the column exp. So I wondered what'd happen if I added more levels to the id_vars in the melt

If I change the melt to

```
pd.melt(df.reset_index(),id_vars=['first','second','A'])
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: arrays must all be same length

If I change the melt to

```
pd.melt(df.reset_index(),id_vars=['first','second','dog'])
```

I get the following error:

> KeyError: 'dog'

Can someone explain what's intuitively going on under the hood with the reset_index() and why doesn't melt accept other levels? Why are 'first' and 'second' showing up as levels instead of columns?

Comment: You have a `MultiIndex` on the columns, so `df.reset_index()['first']` will slice your columns where the 0th level is `'first'`. If you did `df.reset_index()['A']` you'd return the DataFrame of both Series `('A', 'cat')` and `('A', 'dog')`, which is why it complains. The data provided needs to be 1-D for each id_var, so something like `id_vars=['first', ('A', 'cat')]` *would* work

Comment: Thank you! This is what I suspected. `id_vars=['first', ('A', 'cat')]` helped me get this straight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function called `stack`

```
yourdf=df.stack([0,1]).reset_index(name='value')
```

Comment: Also almost same issue ticket open in Git https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17676; and A here is not the same length with your index , it is contain 2*len(df) items , which index only contain len(df)